# time difference between two nsdates

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate

My goal is to make a countdown label. So, for example, I would like to show the difference between the time 19:00:00 and current time. I have written a code below for it.
Also, I have stored a time using sqlite; 19:00:00.

```
    //start time
    NSString *starttime = mission.starttime;
    NSDate *starttime_convert;
    NSDateFormatter *formatttter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatttter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    starttime_convert = [formatttter dateFromString:starttime];

    //current time
    NSDate *nowtime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];
    //NSLog(@"Current Time %@", nowtime);

    float countdown = [nowtime timeIntervalSinceDate:starttime_convert];
    int hh = (countdown/3600);
    NSLog(@"%d",hh);
    int mm = ((countdown-(hh*3600))/60);
    int ss = countdown-(hh*3600+mm*60);
    NSLog(@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hh,mm,ss);
```

However, the results that would be shown is, 122238:43:32.
Since, the current time is 16:44:32, It should show 02:15:68. But it does not.

Could anyone please help me to fix this?

Comment: starttime is 19:00:00, starttime_convert is 323050400:205701184:1088398336, nowtime is 2013-12-11 17:27:09 +0000, countdown is 122239:26:64.

Since I live in Japan, I wanted to compare the starttime and current time in Japan standard time.

Comment: I don't have the time to write a complete solution as an answer, but your start time is converted to "2000-01-01 19:00:00", and not "19:00:00" on the current day.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could convert the start time properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the current date in your starttime instead of only `@"19:00:00"`.

To do that you can use the following code:

```
NSString *starttime = @"19:00:00";
NSArray *times = [starttime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

int hour = [times[0] integerValue];
int minute = [times[1] integerValue];
int second = [times[2] integerValue];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date];
[components setHour: hour];
[components setMinute: minute];
[components setSecond: second];

NSDate *starttime_convert = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];

//current time
//NSDate *nowtime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];
float countdown = -[date timeIntervalSinceDate:starttime_convert];//pay attention here.
int hh = (countdown/3600);
NSLog(@"%d",hh);
int mm = ((countdown-(hh*3600))/60);
int ss = countdown-(hh*3600+mm*60);
NSLog(@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hh,mm,ss);
```

Comment: This seems to be the first answer that addresses the real problem.

Comment: I see, I got it! Thank you very much for the help indeed.

Comment: actually, I have one more question. I have stored the time data into my db, like 19:00:00. In that case how should I state the components sethour, setminute, setsecond ?

Comment: you can parse @"19:00:00" to 19, 0, 0 then set, i will update the answer for that

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I really appreciate your help. The code you have provided for me really helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(startTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


- (void)startTimer {
    double difference = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - self.startTime;
    int hh = 0, mm = 0, ss = 0;
    if(difference < 60) {
        ss = difference;
    } else if(difference/60 < 60) {
        mm = difference/60;
        ss = difference%60;
    } else if(difference/3600 < 24) {
        mm = difference/60;
        hh = mm/60;
        mm = mm%60;
        ss = difference%3600;
    }
    NSLog(@"%2d:%2d:%2d", hh, mm, ss);
}
```

I have checked it for minutes and seconds, working fine. I think It also be working for hours.